# Can't delete file and folder with strange filename on a REFS Server Volume

Tags: filesystems, windows-server-2012

I have an odd problem on a 2012 Server with a ReFS Volume - **Can't delete file or folder with strange filename**. It's our Project Shares there and I think that this problem occurred during a lot of copy/delete processes in a Project Lifetime. Here we worked also with partners in Asia, so I just **suppose that there are foreign characters causing the problem**.
When I wanna delete the File or the parent folder **-> The system can't find the file.**

1. I tried the normal delete of files and folders with Explorer and
   delete CMDs.
2. I tried the `del /S /Q "\\?\R:` cmd
3. I tried with the 8.3 way
4. I tried some tools (I usually use apps like "LongPathKiller" etc.)
5. I tried with Robocopy.....

But everywhere the same problem -> **System can't find the file**.
Because it's ReFS, I can't make a CheckDisk :-(

Is there any Tool or any other Command/Powershell I can use ??
I mean what does MS in such a way ??
HELP !!!